# xslt 2.0/xpath - group adjacent by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML document, and I need to nest/group adjacent elements based on a specified attribute value.  I know this can be done based on an element type or name, but I'm not sure how to do this with given attribute values.  Sample Input:

```
<root>
    <p id="111">5tw5t5et</p>
    <p id="111">4qvtq3</p>
    <p id="222">qv34tqv3</p>
    <j>qv43tvq</j>
    <p id="333">qv43tvq</p>
    <p id="333">q34tvq43tvq</p>
    <p id="333">q3434t3tvq43tvq</p>
</root>
```

Desired output:

```
<root>
    <group>
        <p id="111">5tw5t5et</p>
        <p id="111">4qvtq3</p>
    </group>
    <p id="222">qv34tqv3</p>
    <j>qv43tvq</j>
    <group>
        <p id="333">qv43tvq</p>
        <p id="333">q34tvq43tvq</p>
        <p id="333">q3434t3tvq43tvq</p>
    </group>
</root>
```

I know that I can group by element name using this

```
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="name()">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name()='111'"> 
                  <group>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </group>
                </xsl:when>     
                 <xsl:when test="name()='333'"> 
                  <group>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </group>
                </xsl:when>             
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
```

But I'm not sure what syntax to use to group by the attribute

I've tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="@id">
```

Which throws empty sequence errors, and this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="@id">
```

Which ignores all of the non-p elements.

What is the proper way to group these elements using attribute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:for-each-group`'s `group-adjacent` does not accept an empty `current-grouping-key()`, so you have to handle the elements without an `@id` attribute separately. This can be achieved with an if-then-else expression like `if (@id) then @id else ''` or even easier (thanks to the comments) with `string(@id)`.

So you can change your `xsl:for-each-group` like this:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="string(@id)">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@id='111' or @id='333'"> 
            <group>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </group>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

This assumes that an *identity template* is set up to copy the  elements and attributes.

EDIT: Incorporated improvements suggested in the comments.

**Its output is:**

```
<group>
   <p id="111">5tw5t5et</p>
   <p id="111">4qvtq3</p>
</group>
<p id="222">qv34tqv3</p>
<j>qv43tvq</j>
<group>
   <p id="333">qv43tvq</p>
   <p id="333">q34tvq43tvq</p>
   <p id="333">q3434t3tvq43tvq</p>
</group>
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense...thank you so much!

(Note: I now understand that the second thing I tried -- <xsl:for-each-group select="p" group-adjacent="@id"> -- wasn't throwing empty sequence because all <p> elements have @id.)

Comment: The nested `apply-templates` inside the `for-each` over the `current-group()` can be shortened to `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>`.

Comment: In place of `if (@id) then @id else ''` you can simply write `string(@id)`.